# Check Email in Webmail UFT

Tags: hp-uft, webmail

I am testing an application which sends an email. My requirement is to verify that the contents of the email are as expected. Issue is - the email is sent to test servers which can only be accessed using webmail. Is there any way where from UFT, I can check & verify for email messages using webmail.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution would be to automate the access to your webmail with UFT, is there a reason this is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can automate the webmail navigation and login and then verify the content of the emails. Are you facing issue with this?